# Sync two tables with single SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I need to sync two table in Oracle. I used MERGE to do this job, but I need help to get a working SQL to do this.

My target table has a PK and some other columns. Some of these columns has not null constraint.

My source table has a different layout and data then my target table, so I need to query my source table and convert data to target layout.

My actual code is (simplified):

```
MERGE INTO TARGET t USING(
    WITH SRC AS ( --do the transformation
        SELECT ID, DECODE(VAL,'THIS','THAT','OTHER') VAL1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL,'\d+') VAL2 FROM SOURCE
    )
    SELECT t.ROWID ROW_ID, s.* FROM SRC s
    FULL OUTER JOIN TARGET t ON s.ID=t.ID
) s ON (t.ROWID=s.ROW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.VAL1=s.VAL1 AND t.VAL2=s.VAL2
DELETE WHERE s.ID IS NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(ID, VAL1, VAL2) VALUES (s.ID, s.VAL1, s.VAL2);
```

The problem is that these rows, that match the DELETE condition, throws `ORA-01407: cannot update (string) to NULL`. It seems, that Oracle first tries to update and do the delete later. This causes the ERROR.

The MERGE keyword is really horrible for sync Tables with deletion, but I'd like to use a single Query, because my transformation SQL is really heavy.

Is there any alternative to MERGE or any suggestion what to do, to get this working?

Thanks

Thats my solution. Maybe this can help someone.

```
MERGE INTO TARGET t USING(
    WITH SRC AS ( --do the transformation
        SELECT ID, DECODE(VAL,'THIS','THAT','OTHER') VAL1, REGEXP_SUBSTR(VAL,'\d+') VAL2 FROM SOURCE
    )
    SELECT t.ROWID ROW_ID, NVL2(s.ID,null,1) delFlag, s.* 
    FROM SRC s
    FULL OUTER JOIN TARGET t ON s.ID=t.ID
) s ON (t.ROWID=s.ROW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.VAL1=NVL2(s.delFlag,t.VAL1,s.VAL1) AND t.VAL2=NVL2(s.delFlag,t.VAL1,s.VAL2)
DELETE WHERE s.delFlag IS NOT NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(ID, VAL1, VAL2) VALUES (s.ID, s.VAL1, s.VAL2);
```

But it's really strange that rows that will be deleted must pass constraint checks.

Comment: (When you ask questions and you have an error, please provide the whole error message, not just the error code. I don't know about you, but I'm not a walking encyclopaedia of Oracle error codes! I've edited your question to include the generic error text)

Comment: The query is working, the error comes up on those rows which should be deleted. I wonder why there is a NOTNULL check for those who will be deleted.

Comment: @NicoRichter - because the update is done first, so the constraints have to be met; and then the delete clause ([a sub-clause of update](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) is applied to the result of that update. "The only rows affected by this clause are those rows in the destination table that are updated by the merge operation. The `DELETE WHERE` condition evaluates the updated value, not the original value...". At the point the not-null check is made, Oracle doesn't know/care they will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to delete rows as part of the merge statement, you need to first update the row.

Therefore, you need to take account of null values in the update statement (either directly in the `set` clause, or in the source query), e.g.:

```
MERGE INTO target t
  USING (WITH src AS ( --do the transformation
                      SELECT id,
                             DECODE(val, 'THIS', 'THAT', 'OTHER') val1,
                             regexp_substr(val, '\d+') val2
                      FROM   SOURCE)
         SELECT t1.rowid row_id,
                s1.id,
                NVL(s1.val1, t1.val1) val1,
                NVL(s1.val2, t1.val2) val2
         FROM   src s1
         FULL   OUTER JOIN target t1
         ON     s1.id = t1.id) s ON (t.rowid = s.row_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.val1 = s.val1 AND t.val2 = s.val2
  DELETE WHERE s.id IS NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (id, val1, val2)
  VALUES (s.id, s.val1, s.val2);
```

N.B. I am assuming that the val1 and val2 in the source and target tables are not nullable. Amend as appropriate for your tables.

Answer (score 0):

As weird as it seems, rather than either updating or deleting a row, Oracle's `MERGE` only deletes rows that it already updated. Doesn't seem to make sense, but that's the way it is. **Please see Boneist's answer for a solution.**

Update: I've looked this up in some standard SQL drafts. From what I gather, `MERGE` in standard SQL 2003 only supported insert and delete, and both `WHEN MATCHED THEN` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` were not allowed to appear more than once.

Oracle obviously wanted to provide a delete option and decided for the weird approach to extend the update clause and apply deletes on updated rows only.

In a newer draft (supposedly the current one, found here: https://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html) a delete option was added, the `WHEN` clauses extended to `WHEN MATCHED [ AND <search condition> ] THEN` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED [ AND <search condition> ] THEN`, and these clauses can appear more than once. This looks way better. Let's hope Oracle adopts this new syntax some time soon :-)

> The problem is that these rows, that match the DELETE condition, throws ORA-01407: cannot update (string) to NULL. It seems, that Oracle first tries to update and do the delete later. This causes the ERROR.

Then give the UPDATE part a condition too:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET t.VAL1=s.VAL1 AND t.VAL2=s.VAL2 WHERE s.ID IS NOT NULL
  DELETE WHERE s.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: This won't work - you can't delete the row if you haven't first updated it. See [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a717d07f8c905dd2dc3906eb7a436fc) for a demo.

Comment: Boneist: How strange! I didn't know that. I've edited my answer accordingly.